# Primes and squares

Tags: number-theory

Which is the largest *n* such that, given $S=\{1, 2, 3, ...,  2n\}$, we can pair off the elements of S into *n* pairs so that each pair sums to a different prime or square?

Comment: How far have you tried?  I doubt general theory is going to help all that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I had a few more ideas, but in the end this just turns out to be a more explicit version of* John's *thoughts.*

The pair sums would have to be $n$ different numbers in the range $3,\ldots, 4n-1$. In that range are $\approx\sqrt{4n-1}$ squares and $\approx \frac{4n-1}{\ln(4n-1)}$ primes. Hence as soon as $n$ is larger than about $\frac{4n-1}{\ln(4n-1)}+\sqrt{4n-1}$, such a pairing is not possible.
More precisely, a necessary condition (if $n>5$) is
$$\tag1f(4n-1)-f(2)-4\ge n$$
where $f(x)=\pi(x)+\lfloor\sqrt x\rfloor$. The extra subtraction of $4$ is due to the fact that each of the sums $3,4,5,7,9,11,13$ would consume two summands $\le 12$ and each of the sums $16,17,19,23,25$ would consume at least one summand $\le 12$. As we have only $12$ such summands available, at least four of the sums must be "missing".

One may readily verify that $(1)$ does not hold for $n=72$.
It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function) that $$\frac{x}{\ln x+2}<\pi(x)<\frac x{\ln x-4}\qquad\text{for }x>55.$$ Using this, we find that $(1)$ is false for all $n>1000$. By manual inspection, we fill the gap and find that $(1)$ implies
$$n<72. $$
In particular, $n\in\{64,67,69,70\}$ cannot lead to a solution, and for $n\in\{55,56,62,63,65,68,71\}$, $(1)$ is sharp and hence an explicit solution attempt is extremely likely to fail.

Comment: I think you might be able to polish things off by observing that in order to satisfy the condition, you need $$1+2+\cdots+2n\le(1+4+9+\cdots)+(2+3+5+7+11+\cdots)$$ where you stop summing squares and primes when you get to $4n-1$.  The sequence of running sums of primes less than $N$ is at https://oeis.org/A034387 .  For example, if $n=71$, we have $1+2+\cdots+142=10153$ while $(1+4+\cdot+256)+(2+3+5+7+\cdots+283)=1496+7982=9478$.

Comment: Someone should doublecheck this, but I think the observation in my previous comment takes the upper bound down to $n\le50$, at which point $1+2+\cdots+100=5050$ is less than $(1+4+9+\cdots196)+(2+3+5+\cdots+199)=1015+4227=5242$.

Comment: Continuing my previous comments, you can rule out $n=50$ as well, even though $$(1+2+\cdots+100)=5050\lt5242=(1+4+9+\cdots+196)+(2+3+5+\cdots+197+199)$$ because you can't get all three of $196$, $197$, and $199$ as pairwise sums of six different numbers less than or equal to $100$, so the largest sum we can actually get on the right is $5242-196=5046$.  (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) If I've done all the arithmetic correctly (and again, someone should doublecheck all this), the largest number that can't easily be ruled out is $n=33$, for which $$(1+2+\cdots+66)=2211\lt2357=(1+4+9+\cdots+121)+(2+3+5+\cdots+127+131)$$

Comment: The largest such n is at least 20 because the elements of the set {1,2,3,...,40} can be paired as follows: (1,6), (2,3), (4,9), (5,12), (7,16), (8,11), (10,15), (13,18), (14, 27), (17,20), (19,30), (21,22), (23,24), (25,28), (26,33), (29,32), (31,36), (34,37), (35,38), (39,40).

Comment: Following Barry Cipra's calculations, it would follow that 33 is the answer to my question considering the following pairing of {1, 2, 3,...,66} :(1,4), (2,14), (3,10), (5,6), (7,12), (8,9), (11,18), (13,24), (15,28), (16,20), (17,30),(19,48), (21,32), (22,27), (23,36), (25,39), (26,35), (29,42), (31,52), (33,40), (34,55), (37,44), (38,41), (43,54), (45,52), (46,57), (47,53), (49, 58), (50,59), (51,62), (60,61), (63,63), (65,66).

Comment: Cool!${}{}{}{}{}{}            $

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts.

The maximum sum of two elements of $S$ is $4n-1$.

The number of squares greater than $1$ and less than $4n$ is $\lfloor\sqrt{4n-1}\rfloor -1$.  So if $n=100$ you only have $28$ squares.

There are only $78$ primes between $3$ and $400$.

So you're pushing the upper limit of the answer even at $n=100$, even if you could successfully pair off everything to a unique prime or square.  The larger $n$ gets, the lower the density of primes and squares per natural number.

So, the answer isn't that large.